# Vim color search namely easymotion

Tags: search, vim, colors

Before using anything.
[image]

After Easymotion should be:
[image]

In my vimrc file I've configuration:

```
syntax on
set hlsearch
hi Search ctermbg=none
hi Search ctermfg=Red
```

But Instead what should be I get:
[image]

If I try to reverse "none" and "Red"

```
syntax on
set hlsearch
hi Search ctermbg=Red
hi Search ctermfg=none
```

I get:
[image]

How Can I fix this ? Because write `:hi EasyMotionTarget ctermbg=none ctermfg=Red` every time when I open vim - it's very bad. I need write something in vimrc what will be work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Just need to add:

```
syntax on
hi EasyMotionTarget ctermbg=none ctermfg=Red
```

In your .vmrc